# MonoTouch.CoreAnimation - ошибка анимации

Tags: c#, ipad, monodevelop, monotouch, ios

Применяю анимацию к объекту UIView, анимация проигрывается нормально, но в конце объект становится на прежние координаты. Кто-то может знает, в чем дело?

```
var anim = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("transform.translation.y");
anim.Duration = 1.0;
anim.From = NSNumber.FromFloat(1);
anim.To = NSNumber.FromFloat(100);
anim.RepeatCount = 0;
bookmarksView.Layer.AddAnimation(anim, "bmViewAnim");
```

Comment: C# для iOS? Может, Objective-C?

Comment: Если Эпл принимает в стор скомпилированные в нативный код приложения, то какой смысл переходить на новый язык?
Вообще изначально приложение было создано за неделю на Flex SDK 4.6 во Flash Builder, но на устройстве ipad3, оно падало и тормозило.
MonoDevelop+MonoTouch+С# полностью избавлен от таких проблем. 
Правда сроки выросли до пары месяцев, и это не предел.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не знаю костыль это или нет, но методом "научного тыка" нашел такое решение:
ставить конечные анимируемые свойства до применения анимации:

```
bookmarksView.Layer.Position = new PointF(100, 100); // конечную позицию ставим заранее
var anim = CABasicAnimation.FromKeyPath("position");
anim.Duration = 1.0;
anim.To = NSValue.FromPointF(new PointF(100,100));
bookmarksView.Layer.AddAnimation(anim, "bmViewAnim");
```